# change length of multiple mp3 files

Tags: automation, mp3, trim

I have several hundred short mp3 files (1-5 seconds) I would like to trim them. namely, the length should be rounded up getting a whole second. for example if a mp3 file is 1.32s long, it should be afterwards 2.00 in length, the lack of time should be filled with silence. is it possible to automate this process? if so with what tool? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try Audacity, it allows batch processing: http://manual.audacityteam.org/index.php?title=Batch_Processing

I'm not sure whether it will do everything that you need it to do but it's worth checking out what all your options are within this program.

[EDIT]
Ok, so if you do have hundred and also might be something useful for you in the future this is what I would recommend or would personally do myself.

1. Get [mp3DirectCut](http://mpesch3.de1.cc/mp3dc.html#dwn) [freeware]
2. Get [AutoHotKeys](http://www.autohotkey.com/) [freeware]
3. Learn how to use both, particularly AutoHotkeys
4. Save All filenames into a spreadsheet
5. Create a script that does the following with mp3DirectCut

   - Load file by name on spreadsheet
   - Hit the "End" button
   - Paste a pre-copied silent 1 sec long clip from clipboard
   - Parse the NAV field in the program (bottom left) to get the Total length
   - Calculate and enter desired endpoint to total length for Selection (then hit Enter)
   - Hit the "Del" button
   - Save complete song
   - Repeat

Comment: yes i'm already using audacity but didn't find out how to read the length in batch processing. anyone has a hint?